# Valor randômico em C++

Tags: c++, random

Estava praticando um pouco de C++, criei aquele exercício simples de jogo de dados, então me deparei com um problema, como posso gerar valores randômicos em C e C++?

Dando uma olhada no site ([c plus plus](http://www.cplusplus.com)) encontrei um exemplo utilizando o tempo como *seed* (semente), o problema esta depois disso, criei um código como exemplo, nele estou criando uma classe "Dado" e criando dois métodos, o `Seed` e o "Rolar", um vai criar a semente e gerar um valor e o outro vai passar os valores fixos e chamar o `Seed`, dentro do `main` eu instanciei 3 objetos do tipo `Dado` e fiz a "rolagem", sempre caem os mesmo valores para os 3 objetos, são instancias diferentes, como em outras linguagens, não deveriam gerar valores diferentes? Este é o objetivo, criar valores diferentes para cada dado criado, seguem os códigos:

#### dado.h

```
#ifndef DADO_H
#define DADO_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

class Dado
{
public:
    int Seed(int max, int min);
    int Rolar();
};

#endif
```

#### dado.cpp

```
#include "dado.h"

int Dado::Seed(int max, int min){
   srand(time(NULL));
    return rand() % max + min;
}

int Dado::Rolar(){
    int val_max = 6;
    int val_min = 1;
    return Seed(val_max, val_min);
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dado.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Dado seed;
    Dado dado_1;
    Dado dado_2;

    cout << "Seed:   " << seed.Seed(6,1) << "\n";
    cout << "Dado_1: " << dado_1.Rolar() << "\n";
    cout << "Dado_2: " << dado_2.Rolar() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**makefile** para ajudar quem quiser testar

```
all: main
    rm *.o && ./teste

main: main.o dado.o
    g++ -g -o teste main.o dado.o -Wall

main.o: main.cpp dado.h
    g++ -c -g main.cpp -Wall

dado.o: dado.cpp dado.h
    g++ -c -g dado.cpp -Wall
```

Também criei uma demonstração no [ideone](https://ideone.com/fmxg0N) com algumas alterações, nada que altere o resultado, apenas pra organizar a visualização (não uso muito essa ferramenta, por isso não sei se ele trabalha com mais de um arquivo para fazer o `cpp` e *header*).

Comment: o site  "c plus plus" **não** é documentação oficial...a documentação oficial é fornecida pela ISO através dos países membros (por exemplo [aqui](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+14882%3a2014+%282016%29))...normalmente os "working drafts" do comitê de padronização C++ são suficientes como documentação, além de serem facilmente acessiveis ([aqui](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/)    )... **além disso** o site [cpp reference](http://cppreference.com) geralmente é considerado melhor que o "c plus plus"

Comment: Ok, desculpa, eu pensei que fosse o site oficial, até mesmo pela organização dele, vou dar uma conferida melhor nesse cpp reference, obrigado.

Comment: A documentação chamada e oficial não tem nada de oficial, é uma das principias, a melhor é a http://en.cppreference.com/w/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que está achando que deve criar uma semente nova a cada vez quando na verdade deve criar a semente apenas uma vez.

Ainda tem duas coisas que esse código não é o ideal. A geração randômica do C que foi usada não é muito adequado, é [melhor usar a do C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). E esta classe não está servindo para nada, o máximo que poderia fazer seria encapsular a geração em uma função simples. Criar uma classe para isto é matar passarinho com um canhão. Então fiz de forma mais simples possível. Mas lembre-se a semente só pode ser gerada uma vez.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Dado_1: " << rand() % 6 + 1 << "\n";
    cout << "Dado_2: " << rand() % 6 + 1 << "\n";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/80i6NQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ivzfimkv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Math/Seed.cpp).

Comment: Fiz a alteração aqui no projeto e deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda, não imaginei que fosse tão bobo o problema, mas poderia me explicar a diferença entre o random do C para o C++? Ou seria apenas para adequar a linguagem mesmo?

Comment: Não seria só isso, o do C++ funciona de forma bem aleatória e controle de distribuição. Na verdade nem o do C é tão bom usar, mas não tem nada oficial existente. Quando alguém precisa algo bom mesmo procura usar algo do sistema operacional e não o do C. Quando está em C++ além de usar o mais adequado para ela, é bom usar para já ter algo que funciona melhor. Pra coisas que envolvem segurança não pode nem pensar em usar essa geração falha. Pra jogo não deve causar maiores problemas.